# node.js server code security issue

Tags: node.js, bitcoin

I have a bitcoin account related site, server code is completely node.js.

Everybody will get a bitcoin address after registration. All the private keys are encrypted and stored in google drive using google-api-nodejs-client, the id and secret for OAuth2Client is in a config file.

What makes me uncomfortable is...

**If someday my server is cracked by a hacker, of course he will get my server code and the then he will find out the OAuth2Client related information.**

So what should I do to keep the private keys safe, even my server is cracked?

Answer (score 0):

If the private keys are for users of your application and you do not need them while they are not logged I would recommend encrypting each uniquely with a passphrase from the user which you do not store anywhere.

Comment: user has no password, they sign in with social network account